# Condicional en PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, condiciones

!Buenas!

Estoy realizando un ejercicio, el cual al principio era sencillo hasta que me esta dando problemas el condicional. Imagino que por el error, esta mal definido.

¿Como seria la condición? 
 Este es mi código en **PLSQL**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE datosProfe(vid persona.id%TYPE)
IS
vnif persona.nif%TYPE;
vnombre persona.nombre%TYPE;
vapellido1 persona.apellido1%TYPE;
vapellido2 persona.apellido2%TYPE;
BEGIN
select id into vID from persona;
if vid = persona.id and persona.tipo = 'alumno' then
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Ese ID es de un alumno');
elsif vid != persona.id then
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Ese ID no existe');
else
select nif, nombre, apellido1,apellido2 into vnif, vnombre, vapellido1, vapellido2 from persona where vid = persona.id and tipo = 'profesor';
end if;
END;
```

Y este es el **enunciado** del ejercicio:

> Desarrollar un procedimiento que muestre los datos de un profesor a partir de su id. En caso de no existir el id o de ser un id de un alumno, indicar el mensaje correspondiente.

Si pueden ayudarme a saber como habría que colocar el condicional, lo agradecería. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Que gestor de bases de datos usas? Pues colocaste etiquetas de dos

Comment: Incluye en las etiquetas sólo el motor que usas. Y por favor, incluye el mensaje de error completo que recibiste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veo varios problemas en tu código.

- haces un `select .. into vID`, pero `vID` es el parámetro de entrada, que supongo tiene el ID que nos interesa ubicar. Además ese `select` no tiene una clausula `where`, por lo que va a devolver todos los registros de la tabla.
- En la siguiente línea estás tratando de comparar si `vid = persona.id`, pero `persona.id` no está definido en ese contexto. Dentro de un `if` o cualquier otra sentencia de *PL/SQL* no puedes referenciar directamente nada dentro de una tabla. Lo que debes hacer es traer el dato de la tabla, almacenarlo en una variable local y luego comparar tus variables locales y/o parámetros.
- No tengo un oracle a mano ahora, pero hasta donde recuerdo, en *PL/SQL* las variables que se utilizan en *queries* siempre se prefijan con `:`

En esa línea, el procedimiento podría quedar algo así:
.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE datosProfe(vid persona.id%TYPE)
IS
  vTipo persona.tipo%TYPE;
  vnif persona.nif%TYPE;
  vnombre persona.nombre%TYPE;
  vapellido1 persona.apellido1%TYPE;
  vapellido2 persona.apellido2%TYPE;
BEGIN
  select tipo into :vTipo from persona where id = :vid;
  if vTipo = 'alumno' then
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Ese ID es de un alumno');
  elsif :vTipo is null
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Ese ID no existe');
  else
    select nif, nombre, apellido1, apellido2 
      into :vnif, :vnombre, :vapellido1, :vapellido2 
      from persona 
     where vid = persona.id 
       and tipo = 'profesor';
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('nombre: ' ||vnombre);
  end if;
END;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Me aclaraste mejor las cosas!